# How to append to filename in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I call my batch file like so

```
"c:\mybat.bat" "c:\inputfile.txt"
```

I want to redirect the output to `"c:\inputfile_new.txt"`

Here is my bat

```
@echo off
"c:\myexe.exe" %1 > ????
```

How can I add `_new` to the filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
"C:\myexe.exe" "%~1">"%~dpn1_new%~x1"
```